# Organize SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a licensing database set up for storing my cutomers' records. However, when I need to find someone, it is hard since it is not in alphabetical order.. And I cannot find an option to sort them in Visual Studio's Server Explorer.

Here is a picture, notice the first name letters I did not cut off, they are not in order: http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/4946/captureeg.png

So how do I fix this problem? Is there some secret button in VS I have to discover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using a T-SQL statement, you can rewrite the SQL with an ending of

```
 ORDER BY Name DESC
```

this will allow it to be alphabetical in descending order and ten it will be easier or when searching add a search clause

```
 WHERE Name = 'Earl Smith'
```

if you do comment with more specific in how you are getting the table would be helpful as well.

full Query and of course update customer_records to your table name:

```
 SELECT * FROM customer_records ORDER BY Name DESC;
```

Comment: Hello, I am executing no queries - I just open my server in VS's Server Explorer, right click my table, Show Table Data, and it displays the contents to me.

Comment: Thanks! I found the query designer, tried that, and it worked!

Comment: Donnie you or correct. have edited my answer. With Visual Studio you can not sort your database. You are better off running a sql statement on a seperate page to order it or to access your database directly using SQL Servers built in SQL Query Analyzer and running a SQL Statement.

Answer (score 0):

To be exact - this is by SQL standard. No set has an order UNLESS YOU IMPOSE ONE. Which means a ORDER BY part in a SELECT statement. If you dont do that, the return value is technically random and at the discretion of the database server which will come up in them in an order that is as fast as possible to compute.